# How to install Gwibber from *tar.gz file?

Tags: gwibber

I am very new to Ubuntu and obviously I don't know much about terminal commands.please tell me how can I install Gwibber from *tar.gz file

Comment: First of all, why do you want to install it such way, instead of using Ubuntu Software Center or *.deb package from creators website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unless you face problems with the normal release please use the version used in Ubuntu Software Center**

But since ours is not to question but to answer...

Extract the compressed file, enter the newly created directory and see the README inside the compressed file. These are the 3 commands to do the 1st part:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvfz gwibber-3.6.0.tar.gz
cd gwibber-3.6.0/
```

(if you have another version change the numbers)

Read me file includes the following:

```
Installation
------------

Gwibber uses Python's distutils framework for installation. In order to
install Gwibber, you will need root access. To install Gwibber, perform
the following command as root:

sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: After running sudo python setup.py install I get
can't open file 'setup.py'

Comment: @DibakarBose "Gwibber uses Python's distutils framework for installation" ;) (probably `sudo apt-get install python-distutils` to get setup.py)